# Disable Google Analytics during development - Svelte

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, svelte

I've made a page in Svelte and added Google Analytics. I have some mess in my code, because in `index.html` file I have link
`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX">`

And in `main.js` file I have code like this

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []

function gtag () {
  window.dataLayer.push(arguments)
}

gtag('js', new Date())
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX')
```

I want to disable Google Analytics in development mode. I've tried to use
`window['ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'] = true;`, package called `gtag-opt-in`, but none of this solution helped me.

I'll be grateful for some simple and working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is not technical solution on programming side, but you can try to add this extension on your Google Chrome :

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/developer-cookie/lknhpplgahpbindnnocglcjonpahfikn

it will "pause" Google or other analytic tools to counting any data when you activate this extension.

let me know if this can help :)